# How are "close vote review" questions prioritized? Edit / suggestion

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

When I am reviewing question that are in review to close I most times open the question to read it fully. Sometimes there is a question that already has votes (1) I do my thing (Leave open, close whatever) then go to the next one. The next question could have 2,3 or 4 votes already. Some of these questions are very old, and some very new and there seems to be no particular logic as to how they are prioritized, but I could be wrong.

My question is: What is the priority in the line up?

It does not seem to be by:
amount of close votes already cast or date of question or reason for close.

Edit:

Would it make sense to have the highest number of close votes appear first/have the first priority?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194515/sort-order-on-close-vote-queue